# How to pass \n in csv file so that Salesforce correctly recognizes the new lines in text

Tags: migration

I need to load a csv file with Text field values containing lots of new lines recognized by \n characters.

My question is Salesforce does not recognize \n characters directly and it literally publishes \n characters in the text field instead of going to next line.

What operations need to be performed either at csv side or at Salesforce side to correctly recognize that \n represents new line and Salesforce should put the text post those characters in a new line.

Please advise.

Comment: After research in other communities got this solution approach. Thought to share here for anyone in similar need. Might be helpful : You replace the line break '\n' in excel with CHAR(10) in a formula. The cell would look something like this <="Line1 text"&CHAR(10)&"Line2 text"> OR <=CONCATENATE(A1,CHAR(10),B1)> where A1 is <Line1 text> and B1 is <Line2 text> (remove the angular brackets). I will try the solution approaches and share my results.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce saves a new line as \r\n.  try that instead .

Comment: Tried it in a text field as '\r\n'. Did not work. Please advise.